# JavaScript Making list from array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a list from arrays in JavaScript. I originally used dot notation to define the new values of each variable. However this produces what seems like an infinite list of the first value in the array.

`{value: 10, rest: {value: 10, rest:{etc...}}}`

The code given as a hint is the one commented out in the function below. When run, this gives the correct output (except assigning null to the last rest value which I haven't coded in yet).

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var object = {};
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    object.rest = object;
    object.value = array[i];
    //object = {value: array[i], rest: object};
  }
  return object;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

What is the difference between using the two different methods?

Comment: _"What is the difference between using the two different methods?"_ Which two methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a circular reference with `object`, because you use the same object for assigning to `object.rest`.

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
    var object = {};
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        object.rest = object;
        object.value = array[i];
        //object = {value: array[i], rest: object};
    }
    return object;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

The other example overwrites `object` with an assignment.

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
    var object = {};
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //object.rest = object;
        //object.value = array[i];
        object = {value: array[i], rest: object};
    }
    return object;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

You could use a short ES6 version with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for returning the rest object.

```js
function toList(arr) {
    var result = {};
    arr.reduce((o, a) => (o.value = a, o.rest = {}), result);
    return result;
}

console.log(toList([2, 3, 5, 7, 11]));
```

Comment: Remove redundant result variable.

Comment: @NinaScholz I went over the basics of arrow functions. However, they give the general format of `(parameters) => {statements}`. I'm wondering why your statements are wrapped with () and separated with `,` instead of `;`.

Comment: it's just to omit the return statement, needed with curly brackets. with parenthesis and the comma operator, the arrow function returns the last value, in this case `{}`, assigned to `o.rest`.

Comment: So by putting it in parenthesis, is it being treated as "one" statement that has several parts?

Comment: right. if no parenthesis, then the part `o.rest = {}` is treated as parameter of reduce.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be another implementation for you linked list. You can simply change the link direction by replacing `reduceRight` with `reduce`.

```js
function toList(arr) {
  return arr.reduceRight(function(rest, value) {
    return { value: value, rest: rest };
  }, null);
}

console.log(toList([1, 3]));
```

Comment: you could start with `null`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes that's the fun of reduce.